# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'doc_id' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following script but continue receiving an error that my variable "doc_id" is referenced before assignment, and I cannot find the solution. Please see the code below. I had to cut some of the code but am happy to post as comments if helpful.

Any help is appreciated!

```
def writeBills():
  
    bill_id_list= []

    for item in js.values():
        try:
            bill_id_list.append(item.get('bill_id'))
        except KeyError:
            pass

        bills = getBills(bill_id_list)

        num = 1
        for bill in bills:

            #iterate to the bill key
            #get the doc_id to append to the API call
            try:
                bill_num = bill.get("bill").get("bill_number")
            except AttributeError:
                bill_num = "bill" + str(num)
            try:
                doc_id = bill.get("bill").get("texts")[0].get("doc_id")
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            #append the doc_id to the API call and convert results to unicode string
            searchId = urlopen('https://api.legiscan.com/?key=d43c289757d4acd3bdb73391fb60e97a&op=getBillText&id='+str(doc_id)).read().decode()

            #create json object with API data
            resultsId = json.loads(searchId)

            #iterate to the document object
            resultsId = resultsId.get('text').get('doc')

            #decode the MIME 64 encoded text
            decodedResults = base64.b64decode(resultsId)

            #once decoded, the text is in an HTML string, use bs4 to parse it
            bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(decodedResults)
            for p in bsObj2.find_all('p'):
                if p.string:
                    p.string.replace_with(p.string.strip())
            bsObj2.style.decompose()

            #strip white space, encode in ascii and remove non-printing characters
            htmlText = str(bsObj2.getText())

            f = open("~/repos/LegiScanApiScrips/data/bills/" + str(bill_num) + "_" + str(doc_id) + ".txt", "wb")
            print("Writing: "+ str(bill_num))
            f.write(htmlText.encode("ascii", errors="ignore"))
            f.close()
            num += 1
    
writeBills()
```

Comment: This is one of several reasons why you shouldn't just swallow errors (the empty `except` block)...

Comment: If `bill.get("bill").get("texts")[0].get("doc_id")` fails with an `AttributeError`, `doc_id` will never have been assigned, and therefore not known once you use it in `searchId = urlopen('...'+str(doc_id)).read().decode()`

Comment: Try making doc_id global in function scope.

Comment: `doc_id` is assigned only in a `try` block.  If an exception occurs in that block, you continue on with no value having been assigned to this variable.  You either need to assign some alternate value in the `except` block (as you did with `bill_num` just above), or break out of the loop if further execution is meaningless without that variable.

Comment: In the end, this is a design issue. What do you want to happen when you can't get a doc_id? Maybe its fine and you just `continue`. Maybe it (and potentially index and key errors) get turned into `raise ValueError("Bill doen't not have doc_id")`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
try:
    doc_id = bill.get("bill").get("texts")[0].get("doc_id")
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

There's an `AttributeError` being raise here that you're swallowing so `doc_id` isn't being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `doc_id` only assigns if there is no `AttributeError` but you are using `doc_id` any way.

Try this way instead:

```
doc_id = bill.get("bill", {'text': [{}]}).get("texts")[0].get("doc_id")
```

Try not to involve Exception Handling in your application flow BTW.

Comment: Why not involve exception handling? Simply turning that `pass` into a continue is a great way to silently ignore bills that don't have the data you want. It would also be a great place to put fallback handling or logging if the application design warrants it.

Comment: @tdelaney isn't it an anti-pattern to use exceptions for flow control?